Why did the crowd, who regard Paul as a messiah, get upset by his words?
Paul enters a crowded Fremen prayer area, is challenged by Stilgar to a
deadly duel for the right to speak, but shouts in Chakobsa, as Jessica
whispers to herself to slow down:

Paul (shouts in Chakobsa language): There is no one in this room who
can stand against me. Your mothers warned you about my coming.

Then the crowd stood up, drawing knives out.
Why did the crowd, who regard Paul as a messiah, get upset by his words?

Only the true Messiah denies his divinity.

@Adamant So crowd won't follow him ?

@Adamant - He's not the messiah, he's a very naughty boy.

See? This is a genuine, high effort question about something that may not be readily apparent to people not well acquainted with the world of Dune. Well done, have a deserved +1.

Even though Paul is a revered figure, even considered to be Lisan al Gaib, the Fremen are a proud people with traditions they adhere to.
One is that Paul should challenge Stilgar (and kill him) to speak. He's attempting to get them to realise that he will not kill Stilgar because that would be foolish and, in any case, there is, in fact, no-one who could beat Paul in a fight.
Not challenging Stilgar and suggesting that he could beat anyone there is insulting to the Fremen personally and to their traditions.
He says it differently in the novel..

‘It’s the way!’ some­one shouted.
Paul spoke dryly, prob­ing the emo­tional un­der­cur­rents. ‘Ways change.’
An an­gry voice lifted from a cor­ner of the cav­ern: ‘We’ll say what’s to change!’
...
‘No man rec­og­nizes lead­er­ship with­out the chal­lenge and the com­bat, eh?’ Paul asked.
‘That’s the way!’ some­one shouted.
...
‘Hard tasks need hard ways,’ some­one shouted.
‘Do you smash your knife be­fore a bat­tle?’ Paul de­manded. ‘I say this as fact, not mean­ing it as boast or chal­lenge: there isn’t a man here, Stil­gar in­cluded, who could stand against me in sin­gle com­bat. This is Stil­gar’s own ad­mis­sion. He knows it, so do you all.’
...
‘Many of you have been with me on the prac­tice floor,’ Paul said. ‘You know this isn’t idle boast. I say it be­cause it’s fact known to us all, and I’d be fool­ish not to see it for my­self. I be­gan train­ing in these ways ear­lier than you did and my teach­ers were tougher than any you’ve ever seen. How else do you think I bested Jamis at an age when your boys are still fight­ing only mock bat­tles?’


You might want to extend the quote. It addresses why they're "grumbling"

You are answering from the novel, when the question is explicitly about the 2024 film.

The answer is the same, the quote explains it better
